# How does materialised value work in Akka Stream

Tags: java, akka, akka-stream

I understood that when I run an Akka Stream graph, it will materialised the most right component.

But doing this:

```
Source.range(1,100).to(Sink.reduce((a,b) -> a+b)).run(materializer);
```

Will materialise `NotUsed` though the most left component is a sink that returns integer.

However, doing the same with `runWith` works fine:

```
Source.range(1, 100).runWith(Sink.reduce((a, b) -> a + b), materializer)
                .thenAccept(value -> LOGGER.info("The final value is {}", value));
```

What is it that I didn't understand well about the `run` method?

Answer (score 2):

By default, `to` retains the materialized value of the stream operator that calls that method. In your example...

```
Source.range(1, 100).to(Sink.reduce((a, b) -> a + b)).run(materializer);
//                  ^
```

...the `Source` invokes `to`, so calling `run` on the stream returns the materialized value of the `Source`, which is `NotUsed`, and ignores the materialized value of the `Sink`. This is the equivalent of running `source.toMat(sink, Keep.left())`.

In contrast, calling `runWith` instead of `to` and `run` in this case returns the materialized value of the `Sink`, because `runWith` is a shorthand way of using `Keep.right()`.

From the [documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.6/stream/stream-quickstart.html#materialized-values):

```
final CompletionStage<Integer> sum = tweets.map(t -> 1).runWith(sumSink, system);
```

> `runWith()` is a convenience method that automatically ignores the materialized value of any other operators except those appended by the `runWith()` itself. In the above example it translates to using `Keep.right` as the combiner for materialized values.

Comment: but that is not what I am asking about. I am asking about the materialised value of the run method, and why it is not the same as the materialised value of the related sink

Comment: The run method returns the materialized value of the whole graph. The materialized value of the whole graph is determined by the last operator, in your case of 'to'. 'to' connects a Source to a Sink, and returns the materialized value of the 'left side', of the Source. You seem to want the materialized value of the 'right side', of the Sink. You can achieve that by using `toMat` instead and explicitly specifying you want to `Keep.right`. Then the graph will produce the 'right' materialized value, as will the `run` method. You can use the 'runWith' shorthand which is a bit easier to read.